# About the motivation behind a proof

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm wondering about the motivation for proving the limit.

$$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 1} \sqrt[n] {x} =1 $$

I saw the solution, which uses the squeeze theorem.

> **Solution.** a) Fix $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Let's show first that $\lim_{x \to 1} \sqrt[n]{x}=1$. Denote by $\sqrt[n]{x} = y$ then $y^n=x$ and using standard identity we have $$|1 - x|=|1-y^n|=|1-y|\cdot|1 + y + y^2 + \cdots + y^{n-1}| \geq |1 -y|$$ since $|1+y+y^2+\cdots y^{n-1}| \geq 1$ for $y \geq 0$. Thus, we have $$0 \leq |1 - \sqrt[n]{x}| \leq |1-x|.$$ Using the squeeze theorem and the fact that $\lim_{x\to 1}(1 - x) = 0$, we prove a) in the case of $a = 1$.

Even though I understand this, I don't know how to come up with this idea.

When proving this, I thought about using the squeeze theorem, but I failed.

When trying using squeeze theorem, I attempt to find inequality like :
$g(x)$<$\;\sqrt[n] {x}\;$<$\;f(x)$
and inequality like :$g(x)$<$\;\sqrt[n] {x}-1\;$<$\;f(x)$.

However, I finally give up. Then I see the solution, and it uses the absolute value to find the inequality. Even though the solution is correct, I think this is slightly unreasonable and logically disconnected, because I don't see any hints for using absolute value.

Therefore, I want to ask that is there some clues in this question that motivate us to use absolute value or is there a better and more "natural" way to use squeeze theorem for this?

Comment: You don't need to worry about absolute values. Whoever writing the solution is just trying to combine the cases of left and right limits.

Comment: Could you please explain more about the left and right limits in this question? I actually don't quite get it.

Comment: $x>1$ iff $y>1$. In this case you will be analyzing the difference $x-1$ and $y-1$. When $x<1$, you will be analyzing $1-x$ and $1-y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets go to the definition of the limit.

$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0 : |x -1| < \delta \implies | \sqrt[n]x - 1| <\epsilon$

The "trick" here will be very similar to the one above, but it might look more natural here.

Multiplying by "1."

$\left|\frac {\sqrt[n]x - 1}{1}\frac {1 + \sqrt [n] x + \sqrt [n] x^2 + \cdots + \sqrt [n] x^{n-1}}{1 + \sqrt [n] x + \sqrt [n] x^2 + \cdots + \sqrt [n] x^{n-1}}\right| = \left|\frac {x - 1}{1 + \sqrt [n] x + \sqrt [n] x^2 + \cdots + \sqrt [n] x^{n-1}}\right|$

let $\delta \le 1$ then  $x> 0$ and $1 + \sqrt [n] x + \sqrt [n] x^2 + \cdots + \sqrt [n] x^{n-1}>1$

$| \sqrt [n] x - 1 | < |x-1| < \delta$

let $\delta = \min (1,\epsilon)$

Answer (score 1):

You complaint here seems to be roughly that you don't see the intuition for how to choose the right bounding functions for the squeeze theorem? That is a common complaint about proofs like that and in my opinion also a pedagogical error in how we teach analysis (calculus and related fields). While it is sufficient for the purposes of the argument to simply state the candidate functions and then prove that they suffice, it does nothing to illuminate how to go about selecting those functions so that the argument will follow as desired. This problem is not unique to applying the squeeze theorem, it also shows up all the time when you need to prove that there exists a $\delta$ for any given $\epsilon>0$ such that [insert content that is to be proved here]. Often the proof simply declares what delta will be and then shows that it works, offering no insights into how to find a delta that will work. In general, as a student of analysis, you want to try and learn the various strategies and tactics used to find the right bounds. There are some facts that you prove along the way in a formal calculus class (like Advanced Calculus) that can help with knowing what form a suitable bound might take, but in general is there is a certain amount of educated guess work involved. Once you find one that works, the rest of argument proceeds exactly like it is normally shown in most textbooks. In my opinion, it would be good pedagogical practice for textbook proofs to show explicitly how that selected their bound (or delta value, etc.).

(I gave this as an answer because it was too long for a comment)

Answer (score 0):

A good idea is to look at smaller cases, and see if you can generalize them. We will "play around" and see if something can work.

Starting with $\sqrt x$. Compare this with the functions $x$ and $2-x$. The following inequalities hold, just from intuitiveness:

- If $x<1$, then $x<\sqrt x<2-x$.
- If $x>1$, then $2-x<\sqrt x<x$.
- If $x=1$, then $x=\sqrt x=2-x$.

If there was some way we could break apart these two linear functions so that $\sqrt x$ was in between them, we would be all good... and we can! We want some new functions $f$ and $g$ such that

\begin{align*}
f(x)=\begin{cases}
x&\text{if }x<1\\
2-x&\text{if } x\geq 1
\end{cases}
\quad\text{and}\quad
g(x)=\begin{cases}
2-x&\text{if }x<1\\
x&\text{if } x> 1
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

You may notice that we have precisely $f(x)=1-|x-1|$ and $g(x)=1+|x-1|$. We can then say that

$$1-|x-1|\leq\sqrt x\leq1+|x-1|,$$

and by the Squeeze Theorem, $\lim_{x\to 1}\sqrt x = 1$.

---

So the final inequality above is what we are striving for to show properly. Notice that

\begin{align*}
1-|x-1|\leq\sqrt x\leq1+|x-1|&\iff-|x-1|\leq\sqrt x-1\leq|x-1|\\
&\iff|\sqrt x -1|\leq |x-1|\\
\end{align*}

Notice that we can factor $x-1$ to $(\sqrt x-1)(\sqrt x+1)$, so we have

\begin{align*}
|\sqrt x -1|\leq |x-1|&\iff |\sqrt x -1|\leq |\sqrt x-1||\sqrt x+1|\\
&\iff 1\leq |\sqrt x+1|
\end{align*}

The last inequality is always true, so we have finally built a way to get our proof.

---

Proof that $\lim_{x\to1}\sqrt x=1$:

We have

\begin{align*}
1\leq |\sqrt x+1|&\iff|\sqrt x -1|\leq |x-1|\\
&\iff -|x-1|\leq\sqrt x -1\leq|x-1|\\
&\iff 1-|x-1|\leq\sqrt x\leq1+|x-1|
\end{align*}

By the Squeeze Theorem, $\lim_{x\to 1}\sqrt x=1$.

Now, to generalize.

---

You could then play around with $\sqrt[3]x$ the same way, and you should get to the following proof that $\lim_{x\to1}\sqrt[n]x=1$:

We have

\begin{align*}
1\leq |(\sqrt[n]x)^{n-1}+(\sqrt[n]x)^{n-2}+\dots+\sqrt[n]x+1|&\iff|\sqrt[n]x-1|\leq |x-1|\\
&\iff -|x-1|\leq\sqrt[n]x -1\leq|x-1|\\
&\iff 1-|x-1|\leq\sqrt[n]x\leq1+|x-1|
\end{align*}

By the Squeeze Theorem, $\lim_{x\to 1}\sqrt[n]x=1$.